# Very large "delete from" statement with "where" close, should I optimize?

Tags: sql, database, sybase

I have a classic "sales" database that contains millions of rows in certain tables. On each of these large tables, I have an associated "delete" trigger and "backup" table.

This backup table keeps "deleted" rows for the last 7 days : the trigger starts by copying deleted rows into that backup table, then will perform a delete in the backup in this fashion :

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.TRIGGER
ON dbo.EXAMPLE_DATA
FOR DELETE AS
INSERT INTO EXAMPLE_BACKUP
select getDate(), *
from deleted
DELETE from EXAMPLE_BACKUP
where modified < dateadd(dd, -7, getDate())
```

The structure of the backup table is similar to the original data table (keys, values). The only difference is that I add in the backup tables a "modified" field, which I integrate to the key.

A colleague of mine told me I should use "a loop" because my delete statement will cause timeouts/issues as soon as the backup table contains several millions of rows. Will that delete actually blow up at some point ? Should I do something in a different manner ?

Comment: If this is relevant, I am using Sybase 12.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Sybase 12.5 supports table partitioning; if your design is such that the data can be retained for exactly 7 days (using a hard breakpoint), you could partition your table on the day of the year, and construct a view to represent the current data.  As the clock ticks past a certain day, you could truncate the older partitions explicitly.

Just a thought.

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc20020_1251/html/databases/X15880.htm

Otherwise, deleting in a loop is a reasonable method for deleting large subsets of data without blowing up your transaction log.  Here's one method using SQL Server:

http://sqlserverperformance.wordpress.com/2011/08/13/gradually-deleting-data-in-sql-server/